# Showing images into a list view

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I am writing a code in C# to show the unknown number of images from a specified folder into a "listview" I don't know how to get all the files present in that specific folder.
I know I have to use a loop and array but I don't know how. 
Here is the code which I use to access files with the "known name of file".
It's a windows form app.

```
private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList imgs = new ImageList();
    imgs.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);

    string[] paths = { };
    paths = Directory.GetFiles("TestFolder");

    try
    {
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    listView1.SmallImageList = imgs;
    listView1.Items.Add("2",0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

[image]

and the code is :

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        imageList1.Images.Clear();

        string[] pics = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( "pics//");
        listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
        listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);
        foreach (string pic in pics)
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pic));
        }


        for (int j = 0; j < imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
        {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

            item.ImageIndex = j;

            listView1.Items.Add(item);


        }

    }
```

and at designer set this:

[image]

Comment: files are in a folder and that folder is in debug folder of app. i think i don't need any path then, just the name of folder.

Comment: @Uniquedesign , please take look at updated code , I have moved some lines before foreach , because setting imageList.ImageSize will clear all images and this makes you to load images twice . by doing this , the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Oh, Ok thanks. it's working quite well now. thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the image files you can do

```
IEnumerable<string> paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"Your Dir", "*.*").Where(x=>x.EndsWith(".png") || x.EndsWith(".jpg")); //add all the extensions you wish in
```

then you can just iterate thru the list to add them in

Comment: @Uniquedesign this will be your new paths variable.

Comment: @Uniquedesign just replace your string[] path.....path = Directory .... with the given code

Comment: Done but it's showing error in x.EndsWith(".png")   error is does not exist in current context                                                                                            
  and x=>x    ',' expected

Comment: @Uniquedesign sry got an extra => in there. should be fine now

Comment: @Uniquedesign time for you to do some debugging then. First see if the image extension is png/jpg, if not add them into the or statement. Then see if the paths variable got all the file path you want. And check that your code works for single image.

Comment: Thank so much @Steve it's working. God bless you. :)